# Split column to multiple columns by using R or python

Tags: python, r

I have a value like that and I would like to split it to multiple columns

```
[['Alonso, O.', 'Mizzaro, S.'], ['Gao, H.', 'Barbier, G.', 'Goolsby, R.']]
```

I just wanna the value like

```
'Alonso, O' 'Mizzaro, S' 'Gao, H' 'Barbier, G' 'Goolsby, R'
```

How can I use the RegEx in R or Python to do that?

Comment: Why do you need regex here ? In R, you can just `unlist` the list. `unlist(my_list)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tidyverse try, in R:

**First part**
I assumed this value is for instance a character value in a vector.
So, I loaded your value in a vector like this:

```
char <- "[['Alonso, O.', 'Mizzaro, S.'], ['Gao, H.', 'Barbier, G.', 'Goolsby, R.']]"
```

Then, if you want to split these into separate names, yielding a vector containing the five names as separate values, you can do something like this:

```
char %>% 
  str_replace_all("'|\\[|\\]", "") %>% 
  str_split("\\., ") %>% 
  unlist()
```

Output:

```
[1] "Alonso, O"   "Mizzaro, S"  "Gao, H"      "Barbier, G"  "Goolsby, R."
```

What this does is:
1. get rid of all ''s, ['s and ]'s, by using the string "'|\[|\]". The square brackets need escaping, therefore the double \; the "|" is OR
2. split based on the string "., ". In this case, the dot in that string needs escaping, since we want to use it as a regular dot, not a special character dot.
3. unlist, into a vector of five names in this case.
I used two packages from tidyverse for this, so make sure to install and load tidyverse as a whole, or at least stringr, and magrittr

**Second part**
Secondly, I noticed that in your title you mentioned splitting it into columns.
If this is a value in a variable, that needs to be split into five values in five columns, you could use something like this.

```
char %>% 
  enframe(name = NULL) %>% 
  mutate(value = str_replace_all(value, "'|\\[|\\]", "")) %>% 
  separate(value, into = c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5"), sep = "\\., ")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  name1     name2      name3  name4      name5      
  <chr>     <chr>      <chr>  <chr>      <chr>      
1 Alonso, O Mizzaro, S Gao, H Barbier, G Goolsby, R.
```

This code explained:
1. turn the char vector into a tibble, putting the character value in the variable called "value" in this case (the default name)
2. again step 1 from first part, getting rid of ''s, ['s and ]'s, but this time as part of a mutate call
3. instead of str_split, you now use separate that separates values in a column into separate values over multiple columns. You do have to provide a number of column names into which you think your value will be split ("into = " argument), and the string on which to separate (same string as step 2 in first part).

For this you need three additional tidyverse packages: tibble, dplyr, and tidyr

Answer (score 0):

You can use Extend Method

```
initialValue = [['Alonso, O.', 'Mizzaro, S.'], ['Gao, H.', 'Barbier, G.', 'Goolsby, R.']]

print(initialValue[0])
print(initialValue[1])

x=initialValue[0]
y=initialValue[1]

x.extend(y)

print(x)
```

This will give you more control and you can utilize loops if you have multiple lists to be utilized.

Answer (score 0):

This might help if regex is not mandatory. The solution in `python`.

```
a = [['Alonso, O.', 'Mizzaro, S.'], ['Gao, H.', 'Barbier, G.', 'Goolsby, R.']]
output = ""
for each in a:
    output += " ".join(each)
```

**output:**
`'Alonso, O. Mizzaro, S.Gao, H. Barbier, G. Goolsby, R.'`

Comment: @KeyuSu if this solves your query. Please accept the answer so others with similar question get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it in python

```
cols = [['Alonso, O.', 'Mizzaro, S.'], ['Gao, H.', 'Barbier, G.', 'Goolsby, R.']]

answer_list = [word for lists in cols for word in lists]

answer = ''.join(answer_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the string as `s <- "[['Alonso, O.', 'Mizzaro, S.'], ['Gao, H.', 'Barbier, G.', 'Goolsby, R.']]"`, then you can use the following code to make it, i.e.,

```
r <- unlist(regmatches(s,gregexpr("\\'.*?\\'",s)))
```

such that

```
> cat(r)
'Alonso, O.' 'Mizzaro, S.' 'Gao, H.' 'Barbier, G.' 'Goolsby, R.'
```